# Stuck "s" keystroke after swapping Capslock and Control in emacs

Tags: emacs

By following [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MovingTheCtrlKey#toc2) method, I swapped the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> key for convenience. 
(I am using Gnome Debian run inside virtualbox inside windows 8 host, and I do use AutoHotkey in host)

However, since then I frequently experience stuck keystroke <kbd>s</kbd>, especially when I do <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd>

May I check with the community whether this is a common issue?

(Please help advise. If this is not a common issue, I may have to look into hardware failure possibility.)

Comment: Swapped how? Please include a pointer to instructions and/or a brief summary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use your provided method, instead I use [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MovingTheCtrlKey#toc5). I'm not experiencing any issues. I would recommend using this method over yours since you're modifying an existing layout, whereas using xmodmap you're only swapping 2 X key codes.

If this method still results in your issue then yes, it might be hardware failure.

Comment: thanks.  I will need a little time to test it out thoroughly.